# Spark streaming group rdd by key and group on Paired RDDs and pick latest from each group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

New to spark and scala. Trying to achieve below. My Messages look like below (key, id, version, dataObject)

```
val transformedRDD = processedMessages.flatMap(message => {
    message.isProcessed match {
      case true => Some(message.key, message.id, message.version, message)
      case false => None
    }
  }).groupByKey
```

I want to group by ID on each message and get latest version of message, then groupbykey, then call a predefined method which looks like below

```
Ingest(key,RDD[dataObject])
```

Comment: That does not answer your question, but perhaps will help you choose right module for your needs. Why are you using Spark Streaming if you are _"New to spark and scala."_?!

Comment: I am not seeing any Spark Stream reference in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you should avoid `groupByKey` as it may result in a re-shuffle which can be very expensive. In your use case, you do not require a `groupByKey` and can use `reduceByKey` instead.

```
val transformedRDD = processedMessages
  // notice that we will have Rdd[(String, Message)] or PairRdd after this flatMap
  .flatMap(message => message.isProcessed match {
    case true => Some((message.id, message))
    case false => None
  })
  // after this reduction we will have latest message for each id
  .reduceByKey((m1: Message, m2: Message) => m1.version >= m2.version match {
    case true => m1
    case false => m2
  })
  // now we just want to keep message
  .map({ case (id, message) => message })
```

Comment: Thanks for info... I have to do one more step apart from finding latest version for each id, I have to group by key as mentioned above to collect all rdds going to single table

Comment: sorry. I got it how to write. Thanks a lot